# Calling ARM Template from C#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-resource-manager

I am working on a requirement where I want to call ARM Template dynamically from code passing parameters, like Resource Name, Resource Location etc.,

I am able to create ARM template. For example, created ARM Template for storage account and I have parameter file with values to pass to the template. However these values I want to pass from c# code dynamically and provision the resource in Azure.
From Power shell I am able to achieve this but I want the same to be done from c#.

Any suggestions/technical links that I can explore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think **Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent** solves your problem.

If you look at Microsoft documentation ["Deploy an Azure Virtual Machine using C# and a Resource Manager template"](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/virtual-machines/windows/csharp-template?view=powe), it walks you through deploying a VM using a template file from C#. The documentation could be used as a starting point to deploy any ARM template to Azure.

Comment: Thanks Joseph for your inputs, I have a small question in the parameters.json file
    "parameters": {
        "adminUserName": { "value": "azureuser" },
        "adminPassword": { "value": "Azure12345678" }
      }
azureuser and Azure12345678 these are the values I want to pass at runtime, I mean in UI end-user will provide.  Then how I can pass those values.

Thanks,

Comment: @soundarya9 you can use "WithTemplate" to hand it the Json directly instead of a path https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.resourcemanager.fluent.deployment.update.iwithtemplate.withtemplate?view=azure-dotnet

Answer (score 3):

I use the following function to deploy an ARM Template using c#

```
private async Task DeployTemplate(string resourceGroupName, string deploymentName, JObject templateFileContents, JObject parameters)
        {
            var deployment = new Deployment
            {
                Properties = new DeploymentProperties
                {
                    Mode = DeploymentMode.Incremental,
                    Template = templateFileContents,
                    Parameters = parameters
                }
            };

            var serviceCredentials = await ApplicationTokenProvider.LoginSilentAsync(_tenantId, _clientId, _clientSecret);
            var resourceManagementClient = new ResourceManagementClient(serviceCredentials)
            {
                SubscriptionId = _subscriptionId
            };

            await resourceManagementClient.Deployments.CreateOrUpdateAsync(resourceGroupName, deploymentName, deployment);
        }
```

The templateFileContents get filled by this function:

```
private static JObject GetJsonFileContents(string pathToJson)
        {
            var path = Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location), pathToJson);
            using (var file = File.OpenText(path))
            {
                using (var reader = new JsonTextReader(file))
                {
                    return (JObject)JToken.ReadFrom(reader);
                }
            }
        }
```

This is how I create a dynamic parameters object:

```
var parameters = JObject.FromObject(
                new DbCloneArmParameters
                {
                    databaseName = new ArmParameterValue { Value = databaseName },
                    serverName = new ArmParameterValue { Value = servername },
                    location = new ArmParameterValue { Value = "westeurope" } }
                });
```

Helper classes:

```
public class DbCloneArmParameters
    {
        public ArmParameterValue databaseName { get; set; }
        public ArmParameterValue serverName { get; set; }
        public ArmParameterValue location { get; set; }
    }

public class ArmParameterValue
    {
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
```